# PTP over usb on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, usb, libusb

I am trying to write a small app which can communicate with USB device when connected to a WP7 device. Is it possible to use PTP protocol over USB from a WP7 device? Does a phone needs to support USB host controller to be able to communicate via PTP over USB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not currently possible. The only external access currently provided by the SDK (including the beta Mango release) is via HTTP or network sockets.

While the phone is connected to the PC I believe it can access it's internal IP address, but that's as close as you're going to get for now.